# How to detect lines with only a white space in a text?

Tags: python, string

Given that "empty line" is a white space:

I am trying to read a text file line by line. I want to ignore whitespace lines. Or in a more correct way, I want to detect empty lines.

An empty line can contain spaces, newline characters, etc. And it is still considered as an empty line. If you open it up in notepad, in an empty line you should not see anything.

Is there a quick way of doing this in Python? I am new to python by the way.

Comment: Maybe you also want to know that `len(line.rstrip()) == 0` will check for empty lines, with space or not.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for line in someopenfile:
  if line.isspace():
    empty_line()
```

Comment: I see everyone keep on adding answers of the form `line.strip()==''`, then quickly delete them after they see this answer.

Comment: @gokhan_ufl _"str.isspace() - Return true if there are only whitespace characters in the string_ **and there is at least one character** _, false otherwise."_ Then a strictly empty **line** will produce False because ``''.isspace()`` is False.

Answer (score 2):

Using `strip()` on any string returns a string with all leading and trailing whitespace stripped. So calling that on a line with only whitespace gives you an empty string. You can then just filter on strings with non-zero length.

```
>>> lines=['   ','abc','']
>>> print filter(lambda x:len(x.strip()),lines)
['abc']
>>>
```